# How to write Inner HTML with Flask?

Tags: python, html, flask

I need to add some text in a HTML file, using Flask, with HTML tags enabled.
If the HTML file looks like `{{name}}`, I can use flask like this:

```
@app.route('/')
def main():
    return render_template('template.html', name='name')
```

However, if I try the code below, the text between the `<b>` tag isn't bold.

```
@app.route('/')
def main():
    return render_template('template.html', name='<b>name</b>')
```

How can I change this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using

```
{{ name | safe }}
```

Is there a reason you can't / don't want to do `<b>{{ name }}</b>`? Do you want different formatting depending on the name? In the case you could also use css and classes that depend on the name.

Comment: The reason that I can't use `<b>{{ name }}</b>` is because the tags will be contained inside the name variable.

EDIT: {{ name | safe }} worked. Thanks! I wonder what does the "|" do?

Comment: Jinja (the templating engine flask uses) has something called [filters](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/#id11). The `|` is basically like calling any of the filters with the thing on the left side as its first argument. So what we are actually doing is calling `safe(name)` and the result is printed into the html. There is a bunch of [built in filters](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/#list-of-builtin-filters), which are enough for most use cases, but jinja also allows you to define your own :)

Comment: Putting tags in variables is [often an antipattern](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/233676#233676).